# Terraform to ansible integration. Permission denied issue issue

Tags: ansible, terraform

ssh ansible@ipaddress. getting below error.

**Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**.

I have created one VM with ansible, terraform installed in it. I have created ssh keys by using command ssh-keygen and used id_rsa.pub key in startup script while creating another linux VM through terraform. follow below steps in start up script.

1. created user name as ansible
2. created .ssh folder and authorized_keys file inside folder with 700 permissions.
3. I have used sed command to replace pubkeyauthentication yes.

start up script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "creating user"
useradd ansible
echo "changed to ansible user"
echo "creating .ssh folder"
mkdir -p /home/ansible/.ssh
chmod 777 /home/ansible/.ssh
sudo chown -R ansible:ansible .ssh
touch /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 777 /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
echo "****public key*****"  >> /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo sed -i "s/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

Once VM is created, i navigated to path .ssh/authorized_keys and observed that public key is present. but when i tried to do ssh from source VM am getting **Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**. Can someone help me if anything is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 777 permissions in your script, to both .ssh folder and authorized_keys file. Change appropriate lines to:

```
chmod 700 /home/ansible/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/ansible/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You can use `journalctl -u sshd` to see sshd errors, which will most likely say that your permissions were too open.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created .ssh folder and authorized_keys manually and provided the required permissions. I have copied public key inti authorized_keys but when am trying ssh ansible@ip_address, getting same error.    Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). Did i miss anything here? I'm trying this linux system ( gcp cloud )

Comment: Check sshd logs, what do they say after failed ansible connection? Observe current logs with `journalctl -u sshd -f` and then try your playbook. Also, how exactly have you copied your key? Have you redirected your output with `>` or `>>`, or used plain `cp`? Because in later case you might have overwritten access mode.

Comment: I had missed to update few values. It is working fine. Thanks.